# Run Tornado alongside another asyncio long-running task

Tags: python, tornado, python-asyncio

I would like to run a Tornado server alongside an independent long-running task in `asyncio` in Python 3.7. I'm new to `asyncio`. I've read that you should only call `asyncio.run()` once, so I've brought both tasks together under the `main()` method so that I can pass a single argument to `asyncio.run()`. When I run this code, I get the error `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <function start_tornado at 0x105c8e6a8>`. I'd like to get the code to run without errors, but ultimately I want to know how to do this the right way. The code I've written below feels like an ugly hack.

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

# Fake background task I got from here:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping
async def display_date():
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def start_tornado():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

async def main():
    await asyncio.create_task(start_tornado)
    await asyncio.create_task(display_date)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you use `create_task` with an `async def` function, call the function normally and then pass the result to `create_task`.

   ```
   await asyncio.create_task(start_tornado())
   await asyncio.create_task(display_date())
   ```
2. You don't need to use `create_task` if you're going to `await` it immediately. Use `create_task` without `await` to start tasks in the background, like `display_date()`. `start_tornado` is not a background task in this sense because it doesn't have an infinite loop, it just starts a server that is put into the background by Tornado. So I'd write it like this:

   ```
   await start_tornado()
   asyncio.create_task(display_date())
   ```
3. Since Tornado 5.0, the Tornado IOLoop and asyncio event loop are integrated by default, so you only need to start one, not both. So just remove the `IOLoop.start()` call in `start_tornado`.
4. `start_tornado` isn't currently doing anything asynchronous, so it could just be a normal function. But it would also be a reasonable place to add asynchronous startup logic like establishing database connections, so you can keep it as a coroutine.

Working version of the code with my edits: https://repl.it/@bdarnell/FarawayAdmiredConversions

Comment: The error goes away, but when I run your version of the program it exits after just a single loop. Any idea why? I was expecting the infinite loop in `display_date` to keep the program running indefinitely.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I just needed an additional `await` in front of the `asyncio.create_task(display_date())`

Answer (score -1):

Tornado might already have everything you need.

1. Instead of using `await asyncio.create_task` you can use `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback`
2. Instead of `await asyncio.sleep(1)` you can use `yield gen.sleep(1)`

So in the end the whole code from your example could look like this:

```
import datetime
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen as gen


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


@gen.coroutine
def display_date():
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        yield gen.sleep(1)


def start_tornado():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(display_date)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


start_tornado()
```